# Passing a variable to a table name as a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, variables, declare

I have a bunch of tables that I need to call up in an automated code in SQL Server. They are labeled as such:

```
dbo.enc_TN_2022
dbo.enc_TN_2021 
dbo.enc_TN_2020 
dbo.enc_TN_2019 
dbo.enc_TN_2018
```

Can I do something with a declare statement and pass a variable to the table names?
Something like

```
Declare @yr INT
SET yr = '2022'
Select Top 10 * from dbo.enc_TN_' + @yr + '
SET yr = '2021'
Select Top 10 * from dbo.enc_TN_' + @yr + '
SET yr = '2020'
Select Top 10 * from dbo.enc_TN_' + @yr + '
SET yr = '2019'
Select Top 10 * from dbo.enc_TN_' + @yr + '
SET yr = '2018'
Select Top 10 * from dbo.enc_TN_' + @yr + '
```

I could throw a CASE or a LOOP in there I imagine to clean it up but how can I do this?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Ideally, fix your design; don't have 1 table per year, have 1 table with a column for the year.

Comment: Yeah I can't change the design of the tables.